# get google chrome to view an rss feed

Tags: php, css, google-chrome, rss

I have an .php script that generates an RSS-Feed dynamically.

I want to link a .css stylesheet to this script to enable browsers that don't have a builtin RSS-viewer to display this feed. I do this with

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\r\n";
echo "<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/css\" href=\"rss.css\" ?>\r\n";
```

as the first output commands of the .php-file.

However, browsers like chrome still don't display the feed as webpage - instead chrome shows me the code of this page.

From this tutorial, I know this is somehow possible...

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/208.cfm
http://www.petefreitag.com/rss/

how can this be done?

Comment: my feed contains material with copyrights, therefore I cannot make it public. If necessary I will try to provide a feed with "dummy" information.

Answer (score 3):

You should add the `header` call to specify content type, like this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml");
```

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-phprss/ for more information.

Comment: Do you receive this header on browser side? You can check it in the 'Network' tab of debug console.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976383/xslt-works-in-ie-not-in-chrome-or-firefox) it should be `application/xml` to work in Chrome.

Comment: at least in firefox I receive it... I will check this tomorrow!

Comment: hm, I've controlled it in Chrome now. This is what I get: `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`. In the beginning of my feed I have: `header('Content-type: application/rss+xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\r\n";
echo "<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/css\" href=\"$styleSheet\" ?>\r\n";
echo "<rss version=\"2.0\" xmlns:atom=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">\r\n";`