# Make chrome display an rss feed (2)

Tags: php, xml, google-chrome, rss

This question is a follow-up on this one:
[get google chrome to view an rss feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114819/get-google-chrome-to-view-an-rss-feed)

I copied the source code from this page (hope this is ok for the site-owner):
http://www.petefreitag.com/rss/.
I escaped all quotes and made a php file out of it. The file looks like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/css\" href=\"http://www.petefreitag.com/rss/simple_style.css\" ?>

<rss version=\"2.0\">
    <channel>
        <title>Pete Freitag's Homepage</title>
        <link>http://www.petefreitag.com/</link>
        <description>Covering ColdFusion, Java, Web Development, and other topics</description>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <lastBuildDate>Fri, 23 Mar 2012 18:57:00 GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <ttl>45</ttl>

        <item>
REST OF THE SOURCE CODE
</rss>
";
?>
```

Here you can see the result:
http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0250890/rsstest/test.php

However, on http://www.petefreitag.com/rss/ chrome views the page as rss feed, in my example it shows just the source code.

What is the difference and how can I force chrome to view the page as rss feed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the header to `application/xml`

This worked for me by changing the header:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo file_get_contents('http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0250890/rsstest/test.php');
?>
```

Mozilla accepts a whole range of headers

`text/xml`,`application/xml`,`application/rss+xml`,`application/atom+xml`

But it seems chrome accepts only `text/xml` or `application/xml`

Not 100% sure why, perhaps you should take it up with google ;p

Comment: 'application/xml' works, but shouldn't 'application/rss+xml' also work? Isn't the second one the correct mime type?

Comment: You can request Chrome changes it behavior by opening a new issue: http://crbug.com/new

Answer (score -4):

Add doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: this doctype describes an html document, not an rss feed