# Chrome displays RSS feed as plain text

Tags: c#, xml, rss, xmldocument

During one of my developments, i had to copy a RSS feed on one of my servers and with chrome (only) the RSS is rendered as text !

this is the code i used to copy the feed, i just only keep the 10 first "items" nodes, the rest is just the same:

```
 protected string rss()
 {
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    string html = "";
    try
    {
        xdoc.Load("/myfeed.xml");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Response.Write(e.ToString());
    }
    XmlNodeList projectNodes = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

    for (int i = projectNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(i>9)
        {
            projectNodes[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(projectNodes[i]);
        }
    }
    return xdoc.InnerXml;
 }
```

Does anyone know why i have this problem only with chrome ?
Thanks

Comment: What `Content-Type` are you returning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10145973/55209 doesn't setting correct header helps you?

Comment: Thanks , adding a content type solved the problem