# XML XSL is not working with Chrome,FireFox, Opera

Tags: xml, google-chrome, firefox, xslt, opera

I have XML file transformed to html using XSLT. It works well in Internet Explorer but when I tried the same in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, it displays the HTML code and not loading the page.

I google'd and found that xml-stylesheet type should be application/XML for chrome, Firefox. But it didn't work. below is my xml namespace,

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
           xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
```

this is my xml code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<UserTabs>
<ToolInfo>
  <Name name = "test"/>
</ToolInfo>

<BannerTabs>
    <Tab name="HOME" Url="http://www.test.com"/>
    <Tab name="HISTORY" Url="/com/servlet/test.servlet?func=history"/>
    <Tab name="ABOUT" Url="/com/servlet/test.servlet?func=about" absUrl="true"/>
    <Tab name="EXIT" Url="/com/servlet/test.servlet?func=logout"/>
</BannerTabs>


<MenuTabs>

</MenuTabs>


<Navigation>
    <Menu bgcolor="#E0E0E0" name="Change.Language">
        <Item href="/com/servlet/test.servlet?func=customize" icon="bluebutton.gif" name="CUSTOMIZE" target="main" textcolor="blue" value="">
        </Item>
    </Menu>


</Navigation>   

<languages>
    <lang name="English (en)" Url="en"/>
</languages>




<runtime>
</runtime>
</UserTabs>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976383/xslt-works-in-ie-not-in-chrome-or-firefox?rq=1

Comment: i already tried changing the mime type(the solution given in the link you mentioned) to application/XML but still its not working.

Comment: Could you show us where your XML is referencing the XSLT file? That's probably more relevant than what you've shown so far.

Comment: hi, i have added the xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for my own question after searching and googling,

My XSL and XML namespace were correct but i need to add in the servlet also the response content type both in doGet and doPost. 
And I have added it, its working now. MIME types can be found in the below link,

- [Properly Configuring Server MIME Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Properly_Configuring_Server_MIME_Types)

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. Could you please elaborate the solution?