# XSLT works in IE, but nowhere else

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I've seen variations of this question all over the place but none of the solutions provided seem to be working. Which means there's probably some other issue in my code/setup I can't see.

I'm trying to make a site for a relative and I'm having trouble with the XSLT stylesheet. It doesn't seem to do anything in either Chrome or Firefox, but it works just fine in IE10. Which is something, but not what I'm after.

The site is set up in IIS 10 and I can browse to it using a local url.

The XML is built from a stored procedure, called in C#:

```
private void buildXML()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-[SERVERNAME]; database= local; persist security info=True; Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.setIndexXMLData", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        string xmlPrefix = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xml\" href=\"/XSLT/Index.xslt\"?>";
        xRead = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
        xRead.Read();
        xmlPrefix += Environment.NewLine + xRead.ReadOuterXml();
        pXml.LoadXml(xmlPrefix);
        Response.Write(pXml.OuterXml);


        // Define the contents of the XML control
        xDoc.DocumentContent = xmlPrefix;
        // Specify the XSL file to be used for transformation.
        xDoc.TransformSource = Server.MapPath("/XSLT/Index.xslt");

    }
```

Which generates this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="/XSLT/Index.xslt"?>
<Site>
  <MENU>
    <SiteMenu Title="[sitename]" Linkpath="/default.aspx" displayOrder="0" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Infomation" Linkpath="/information.aspx" displayOrder="1" />
    <SiteMenu Title="News" Linkpath="/news.aspx" displayOrder="2" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Menu" Linkpath="/menu.aspx" displayOrder="3" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Gallery" Linkpath="/gallery.aspx" displayOrder="4" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Contact" Linkpath="/contact.aspx" displayOrder="5" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Catering" Linkpath="/catering.aspx" displayOrder="6" />
  </MENU>
  <SLIDES>
    <SlideShow imgPath="/20160806_182949.jpg" displayOrder="1" />
    <SlideShow imgPath="/20160901_193700.jpg" displayOrder="2" />
    <SlideShow imgPath="/14202562_319650221718312_9092982335636542049_n.jpg" displayOrder="3" />
    <SlideShow imgPath="/14237745_319766348373366_7639011255502415884_n.jpg" displayOrder="4" />
  </SLIDES>
</Site>
```

And it should be transformed with this XSLT but it doesn't seem to load:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method='xhtml' indent='yes' doctype-public='"-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.1//EN"' doctype-system='"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic11.dtd"'/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head runat="server">
        <title>WEBSITE NAME</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" href="Assets/styles.css" />
        <script src="/Assets/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Assets/scripts.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:700" rel="stylesheet"/>
      </head>
      <body>
[VARIOUS DIVS AND FOR-EACH LOOPS FOR MAKING A COUPLE OF MENUS]
      </body>
  </html>
```

This all results in a page that loads just dandy in Internet Explorer (but, having separate CSS issues which I honestly don't care about), but in both Firefox and Chrome I am left with a blank white page, with the XML available in the dev-tools (but none of the html, just unstyled XML)

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, what should I do now?

Comment: This looks like a dupe, although I can't be sure. Can you check [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1976417/14357) and tell me if it's applicable.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change anything. I made the change to this line  of the C# method: `string xmlPrefix = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><?xml-stylesheet type=\"application/xml\" href=\"/XSLT/Index.xslt\"?>";`

Comment: Does the developer console of Firefox or Chrome not indicate any error message as to what failed? I see two strange issues in your post, `xsl:output method='xhtml'` does not exist in XSLT 1.0 so I would expect an error related to that and suggest to use `method="xml"` if you want to generate XHTML or `method="html"` if you want to generate HTML(4 or 5, which seems more appropriate these days).

Comment: The other strange issue is that you use `esponse.Write(pXml.OuterXml)` to write the XML to the client but also seem to use some server-side control. That raises the question as to where you want the XSLT to happen, in the browser or on the server?

Comment: @MartinHonnen the answer your first comment is that I was just trying stuff out. I've tried it with both 'xml' and 'html' with no difference in result. The answer to your second question is that I'm not very bright and just kept adding to the C# method until something displayed. I'm not sure which approach is best.

Comment: XSLT is a server-side technology. The client-side support is too fragmented and to incompatible among each other to be dependable. Either you provide the XSLT processor yourself (there are XSLT implementations for JS), or you accept that there will be platforms that are incompatible with your solution - or you do the only sensible, predictable and stable thing and convert your XML on the server.

Comment: @Tomalak sounds like a good idea, can you pretend I'm an idiot and point me in the direction of somewhere to learn how to do that?

Comment: XSLT support [is built into the .NET framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47yh29a9(v=vs.110).aspx). There are plenty of examples on this site and elsewhere that get you started.

Comment: @Tomalak, although we're increasingly moving to Saxon-JS for client side XSLT transformation, we also use the XSLT 1.0 processors in the browser and have very little trouble with them.

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes, but unless things have changed radically, integrated XSL transformations via `<?xml-stylesheet>` are still hit and miss. It's possible with the help of JS to work around browser incompatibilities, but the more predictable and easy-to-manage way would be to not worry about the client side and do the transformation on the server. (Of course that's just an opinion.)

Comment: @Tomalak We're using this approach for serving pages like http://www.saxonica.com/products/feature-matrix-9-7.xml, and it seems to work perfectly reliably.

Comment: @MichaelKay The page fails in IE with IE8 rendering mode (not terribly likely to be a problem in the wild, in corporate environments old IE is - sadly - still an issue. Not sure about other user agents.) Maybe I'm over-cautious, too.

Comment: @ChrisHinton It's not clear from your comments that you properly understood the answer I linked to. It does not refer to changes in any of the XML documents... rather it's about the content-type header that is sent from the server when the browser requests this document. Did you check this? [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) can be very useful for this.

Comment: @spender Thanks for the tip, I added a `Response.Type = "application/xml" to the c# method and it works now. If that makes this a dupe of that other problem, feel free to mark it as such.

Comment: @ChrisHinton Yes, I must fulfill my civic duty and apply the dupehammer. Glad you got to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is probably

```
type="text/xml"
```

The form that works reliably is

```
type="text/xsl"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I must be missing something else because unfortunately that didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you loading from a file: URI or an http: URI? There may be cross-site scripting rules. Also, the media type in the HTTP response may be relevant (classically, IE uses the file extension in the URI where other browsers use the HTTP media type). I would expect to see something in the developer console when it fails.